# how to handle pagination in rest api automation

Tags: java, api, groovy, automation, pagination

How can I handle pagination in rest API?

```
public getMethodForCenter(String baseUrl, String endpoint) {
    HttpURLConnection openConnection = new URL(baseUrl + endpoint).openConnection()
    def token = postAuthorization(Users.username, Users.password)
    openConnection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    openConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
    if(openConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
        assert openConnection.getResponseCode() == 200
        def responseBody = openConnection.getInputStream().getText()
        def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(responseBody)
        assert parsedJson.statusCode == 200
        return parsedJson
    } else {
        assert openConnection.getResponseCode() != 200
        def responseBody = openConnection.getErrorStream().getText()
        def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(responseBody)
        assert parsedJson.statusCode == 200
        return parsedJson
    }
}
```

I have to test pagination, but how can I handle and create pagination links? for example, I have 5 optional fields: id, createDate, modifiedDate, Name and etc.
I was thinking to create links by myself using if/else statement, but there will be too many variations and I think that it is not the correct way to do that.
This is what I mean for one field:
adding one value - `getMethodForCenter(String baseUrl, String endpoint, String name)`
and then make an if/else statement:

```
if(name == null) {
  HttpURLConnection openConnection = new URL(baseUrl + endpoint).openConnection
} else {
  HttpURLConnection openConnection = new URL(baseUrl + endpoint + "?Name=${name}"
}
```

**EDIT: ** another way is to add `String path` and pass path by myself

Comment: why you use the over-complicated java sdk to make requests instead of groovy standard https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/ ?

Comment: Hmm, I've found this method and I feel comfortable now with that. I will take a look at http builder

Comment: But, how to handle this problem ? pagination and filters ?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply [http-builder](https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/), your code would reduce to bare minumum, and hence you will be able to test all combinations of params with ease.

Usually pagination are represented by optional request parameters like, `max`, `offset`, `first` etc.

With that said your code could boil down to smth like:

```
def http = HttpBuilder.configure {
    request.uri = baseUrl + enpoint
    request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer $token"
    request.contentType = 'application/json'
}

def paginationCombos = [ [ 10, 0 ], [ 10, 1], [ 20, 1 ] ] // etc

paginationCombos.each{ pair ->
  def (max, offset) = pair
  def json = http.get {
    request.uri.query = [ max:max, offset:offset ] // here you can add filters
    response.success{ FromServer fs, Object jsonBody ->
        assert jsonBody.statusCode == 200
        jsonBody
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will try that. Also, I've made a mistake in the description. The main problem is "filters". There are too many fields to filter and too many variations for that.